# Angular - how can I take the data from API call and use it to populate a table?

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to take the information received from API call and use it to fill the table.
Also, why is this.movies a blank array when I try and set the value equal to the data.

[image: Here is the data received]

[image]

```html
   

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CinemaService } from './services/cinema.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'movie-app';

  data: any = [];
  constructor(private cinema: CinemaService)
  {
    this.cinema.getData().subscribe(movies=>{
      console.log(movies)
      this.data = movies;
    })

   this.display(this.data);
  }

  display(thing: any)
  {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: you can follow after these examlpes https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 2):

You are subscribing to get data that are asynchronos, and then calling this.display immediatly after.

The problem is that you subscription has not returned with data yet before you call `this.display(this.data)`, `this.data` will contain its initial empty array since the subscription has not changed the content yet.

This code should give you two logs with data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CinemaService } from './services/cinema.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'movie-app';

  data: any = [];
  constructor(private cinema: CinemaService)
  {
    this.cinema.getData().subscribe(movies=>{
      console.log(movies);
      this.data = movies;
      this.display(this.data);
    });
  }

  display(thing: any)
  {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
  
}
```